# Is it possible to show both master and detail in profile orientation?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, master-detail

When I use landscape, I can see my master and detail right next to each other.  Is it possible to have the profile orientation work exactly the same?  My detail view is very small and doesn't need to take up the whole window, also it doesn't even make sense to show the detail view if no item is selected in the master.

I'm talking iPad specifically here.

Comment: You can do anything you want to do. You are writing/creating the software. Do you have a specific problem you need help with?

Comment: side-note: its portrait orientation not profile :)

Comment: Do I have a specific problem? How about the one I just asked about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just implement the UISplitViewControllerDelegate method below:

```
- (BOOL)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc shouldHideViewController:(UIViewController *)vc inOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation {
    return NO;
}
```